# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am currently developing a GUI in Python and have stuck on a function that is supposed to show wipe animation of Image A covering Image B in square frame. When I run the program, I receive these two types of errors:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "g:\2020-2021\Python\Python1\PyProject\src\GUI.py", line 83, in apply_transitions
    frame = get_frame(frame_number)
  File "g:\2020-2021\Python\Python1\PyProject\src\GUI.py", line 79, in get_frame
    frame[x,y] = data_B_norm[x,y]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Canvas
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np
import time

window = Tk()
window.title("Image Transitions")
window.geometry("1200x800")
window.config(background="CornflowerBlue")
window.maxsize(1200, 800)

title1 = Label(window, text="Image 1", width=20)
title1.place(x=180, y=175)
title1.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

title2 = Label(window, text="Image 2", width=20)
title2.place(x=530, y=175)
title2.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

title3 = Label(window, text="Image Transitions", width=20)
title3.place(x=880, y=175)
title3.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

def browse_Image1():
    global image_first, img

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select a File",
    filetypes = (("2D - JPG", "*.jpg*"), ("2D - PNG", "*.png*"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    
    img_opened = Image.open(filename)
    img = img_opened.resize((300, 300))
    image_first = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    label = Label(window, image=image_first)
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=100, y=200)

button1 = Button(window, text="Upload Image 1", width=20, command=browse_Image1)
button1.place(x=180, y=510)

def browse_Image2():
    global image_second, img2

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select a File",
    filetypes = (("2D - JPG", "*.jpg*"), ("2D - PNG", "*.png*"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    img2_opened = Image.open(filename)
    img2 = img2_opened.resize((300, 300))
    image_second = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

    label = Label(window, image=image_second)
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=450, y=200)

button2 = Button(window, text="Upload Image 2", width=20, command=browse_Image2)
button2.place(x=530, y=510)

def apply_transitions():
    ImageA_Width, ImageA_Height = img.size
    data_A_norm = asarray(img2) / 255.0
    data_B_norm = asarray(img) / 255.0
    
    frame_number = 0

    def get_frame(frame_number):
        frame = np.zeros((ImageA_Height, ImageA_Width)) / 1.0
        for x in range(0, ImageA_Width):
            for y in range(0, ImageA_Height):
                if x < frame_number: 
                    frame[x,y] = data_A_norm[x,y] #this is where the issue is
                else:
                    frame[x,y] = data_B_norm[x,y] #this is where the issue is
        return frame
    
    while frame_number < ImageA_Width:
        frame = get_frame(frame_number)
        image_opened = Image.fromarray(frame)
        shot = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_opened)
        label = Label(window, image=shot)
        label.pack()
        label.place(x=800, y=200)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        frame_number = frame_number + 1

button3 = Button(window, text="Apply Transitions", width=20, command=apply_transitions)
button3.place(x=880, y=510)

canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()
canvas1.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas1.place(x=100, y=200)

canvas2 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas2.pack()
canvas2.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas2.place(x=450, y=200)

canvas3 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas3.pack()
canvas3.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas3.place(x=800, y=200)
```

Although it is clear to me that the problem is either with the different types of elements of arrays or different dimensions, I can't figure out what exactly is not matching. img and img2 here are Image type objects.

Comment: Seems like this is really a Pandas or NumPy question.  You might get better help if you added those to the tags.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire error message beginning with the words TraceBack.  You can paste the message into your question and format it as code to make it easier to read.

Comment: This is hard for people to debug because we can't run your code. What is `asarray`? Have you tried using the debugger to see what the value and shape of `data_A_norm` are? Or provide a reproducible code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: The exception message is fairly self-explanatory.  Try adding this line before line 79 and see what happens: `assert(data_B_norm.ndim == 2)`

Comment: Most likely `frame[x,y]` is a single **element** slot in a 2d array, while  `data_A_norm[x,y]` produces an array (a **sequence**).  Your job is to keep track of dimensions.  What is the shape of `frame`?  Shape of `data_A_norm`?  It is derived from an image; is it a color image with a (h, w, 3) shape?